# How do I edit (remove frames from) an animated GIF using Preview (Mountain Lion)

Tags: macos, preview, image-editing

I've been able to access the animated GIF, similarly to [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6307/preview-an-animated-gif-image), but I want to remove frames from the GIF. Is this possible with Preview, or do I need to use a different software?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible!

1. Open the GIF in Preview
2. Click on "View" at the top
3. Click "Thumbnails"
4. Delete frames you don't want
5. Hit save

Comment: This works, but be careful, I've found that some software doesn't respond well to gifs after they have been modified this way. One web project I was working on refused to loop such gifs; another refused to load them at all. Before deleting a frame in Preview, the gifs had worked fine. I suspect Preview is subtly damaging the gifs in some way, but I do not know how/why/etc.

Comment: That's really interesting, thanks for letting me know.